# Xcode cloud and Bitrise CI/CD fails : Use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bitrise, xcode-cloud

I'm trying to build my ReactNative application for IOS using Bitrise and Xcode build pipelines.
Is there any way to skip this issue on CI/CD pipelines?
I'm getting this on Xcode and Bitrise both pipelines.

```
/Users/[REDACTED]/git/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp:2285:9: error: use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands [-Werror,-Wbitwise-instead-of-logical]
```

[Bitrise Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb207.png)

[Xcode Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiSyk.png)

Xcode Archive & Export for iOS

Comment: That's an error during compilation that is causing the build to fail. It looks like you are using the bitwise OR operator (`|`) when perhaps you really wanted to use the logical OR operator (`||`).

Comment: Have you managed to solve your issue, I am facing the same error after upgrading to iOS 13.3 it gives me build failed /react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp:2285:9 Use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands

Comment: I have changed the Bitrise "Stack & Machine" on the workflow editor into **Xcode 14.2.x, on macOS 13.2 (Ventura)** now it builds successfully on **Xcode 14.2.x** stack machine. But it's still the same error on Xcode 14.3.x

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a few weeks ago; all of a sudden, my **TestFlight** builds stopped working. It turns out I had set my builds to use the latest Xcode version in this case 14.3RC, I changed back to 14.2 (14C18)[image: 14.2 (14C18)] and my builds started working again

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Yoga v1.18, fixed in v1.19. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898723).
You can either patch ReactCommon to fix the bug or update react-native to latest and see if that fixes it.