# Use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands | Xcode 14.3 fails builds using react-native Yoga

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode14

Just updated my Xcode to Version 14.3 today and the build is failing with the following error in the Yoga file:

> Use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands

Looks like we have some issues with the iOS Yoga package. I don't want to rollback to lower version again. If someone can help to get over it, that would be nice.

I tried removing cached data and derived data and cleaning the build. Tried removing pods and node_modules as well. But nothing has helped.

Comment: Here's a link to the react-native issue and suggested workaround for react-native 0.66 users: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36758#issuecomment-1496210081

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I resolved it by putting 2 vertical bars "||" instead of one "|" in the code where it is failing.

Then cleared the build and it is working fine now on Xcode 14.3. I Hope this helps someone.

Edit:

Above one is temporary solution.
By using following solution we do not need to make change on every npm installation. It is suggested by @[Carl G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39396/carl-g). @[Mykola Odnosumov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11932340/mykola-odnosumov) 's Solution in this thread is also helpful, it is similar solution.
Thank you @Carl G and @Mykola Odnosumov

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36758#issuecomment-1496210081

1. install patch-package https://github.com/ds300/patch-package
2. Modify the source code like this commit [52d8a79](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/52d8a797e7a6be3fa472f323ceca4814a28ef596)
3. run `npx patch-package react-native`
4. commit your changes. Done.

Comment: Did you have to address this in a CI pipeline?  I need to fix this when the repo is cloned on each build

Comment: This is an excellent temporary solution, but for me, it keeps going back to one `|` every once in a while (I think after each pod install). Is there a better, permanent solution to this?

Comment: Hey @CezarCobuz, I have edited the answer. Please follow above steps so you won't need to make this change on every once in a while.

Comment: Just update "|" to "||" in Yoga.cpp (line:2232) is OK

Comment: after adding this line i get the following build commands failed:
 CompileC /Users/myname/projects/projectname/ios/DerivedData/aido/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/json.o /Users/myname/projects/projectname/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/json.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Answer (score 45):

### General

This issue's been fixed in Yoga v1.19.0

Check out [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/yoga/commit/f174de70afdde2492e8677bd0e716eb41bf64469) dated Apr 12, 2022, and [release v1.19.0](https://github.com/facebook/yoga/releases/tag/v1.19.0) dated May 21, 2021.

### How to fix

1. Update the Yoga package to v1.19.0, if possible.
2. Use `patch-package` for development ease

   1. Add `postinstall` script to `package.json` file with `patch-package` call
   2. Edit `react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp` to fix the issue with incorrect operator used
   3. Execute `npx patch-package react-native` to generate `.patch` file
   4. Make sure to add `patches/` directory to git

Comment: Note that if you are not using standalone Yoga (meaning its a dependency instead), there will be no 1.19.0 available to use. plus, it appears the latest podspec for Yoga is **still** 1.14.0, even on the release tagged 1.19.0, so not sure if that's a mistake on their github?

Comment: correct @stonedauwg, looks like using the patch-package would be the only working solution for now

Comment: Worked for me! No need to clean the project! Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on M1 Max! Thanks!

Comment: Just manually fix the issue in /node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp file node->getLayout().hadOverflow() ||

Comment: after adding this line i get the following build commands failed: CompileC /Users/myname/projects/projectname/ios/DerivedData/aido/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/json.o /Users/myname/projects/projectname/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/json.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods') (1 failure)