# React Native App 0.65 does not work with XCode 14.3

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After running the command `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)"`
I'm getting an error.

> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/{usernamenr}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{projectname}-esaknhfpvzhmyaepfktgsvawzuqy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Yoga.o /Users/{username}/Projects/${projectname}/application/packages/mobile/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
> (1 failure)

I tried to `remove node_modules`, `clear cache` and `install pods`. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a compilation error caused by the yoga library.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897834/use-of-bitwise-with-boolean-operands-xcode-14-3-fails-builds-using-react-n) may be the answer.

Comment: Nope, this does not help