# Build error - use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, graphql-yoga

I have a project of react-native that I have created on an older version of MacBook Air about one year ago. now I have shift the same code to MacBook Pro and I want to build the app every thing work fine. but. I Yoga it says

`Build error - use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands`

it is a larger project and don't want to update all project depdencies because it will take a lot of time.

I have read the react-native GitHub and found this

```
RN versions before 0.69 are no longer being supported. If there is a need to use an old version of RN/Yoga, an older version of XCode is required.
```

Anyway to solve this.

I also have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897834/use-of-bitwise-with-boolean-operands-xcode-14-3-fails-builds-using-react-n) questions but that was closed and not accepting answer. I don't understand that was a high view question but still was closed and not accepting answers.

Comment: Temporary solution - Replace BITWISE  operator `|` with `||` operator - https://github.com/facebook/yoga/blob/main/yoga/Yoga.cpp#L2248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just update "|" to "||" in Yoga.cpp (line:2232)

> Then product -> clean build folder
>
> then product -> build